# APC on Windows IIS 7.0 - C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: php, iis-7.5, apc

I'm trying to run `http://localhost/apc.php` on Windows Server. And occasionally I get this error:

> C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Sometimes it throws this error sometimes it does not. I can test by just refreshing the `apc.php` file.

PHP Log doesn't show any related error. What can be the possible cause?

The specs of the server is below:

```
Intel R Xeon  CPU 3GHZ 3GHZ
2GB RAM
64bit
```

APC & Server specification

```
3.1.7-dev 
PHP Version 5.3.6 
APC Host localhost 
Server Software Microsoft-IIS/7.5 
Shared Memory 1 Segment(s) with 1024.0 MBytes 
(IPC shared memory, File Locks locking)  


extension=php_apc.dll
apc.shm_size=1024M
apc.num_files_hint=10000
apc.user_entries_hint=10000
apc.max_file_size=5M
```

Comment: Have you tried [WinCache](http://www.iis.net/download/WinCacheForPHP) instead of APC? I've tried APC in the past (last time over a year ago) .. and it was NOT stable at all (sometimes  I had to restart website app pool 2-3 times a day as website will not respond at all -- 500 error). With WinCache I had no such problems at all. In case you are using APC functionality from within PHP script (user data cache) -- the WinCache has very similar API.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. I've switch to using file cache instead and the stability is better now. I will explore wincache soon